# How to find database name of any table

Tags: sql-server

How to find the database name for a particular table when we have created a table and we forgot the database where we have created the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found the solution, we can simply find a database where we have created the table.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT  DB_NAME(database_id)
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_operational_stats](NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) = 'tablename'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this EXEC sp_MSforeachdb

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT sc.TABLE_CATALOG, sc.TABLE_SCHEMA, sc.TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  sc WHERE TABLE_NAME=''YourTableName'''
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server 2012 or more then simply you can find DataBase name using INFORMATION_SCHEMA like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='your_table_name'
```

Here TABLE_CATALOG column shows DataBase Name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL Server ready solution to your problem.
To resolve it you need to loop through each database and to put the information schema into new table and then to query it.

Some idea can be found in the site bellow:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/